# How to turn off macbook's internal keyboard when external keyboard connected?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I just wonder if it is possible to completely turn off macbook's internal keyboard when a bluetooth(for example) keyboard(a magic keyboard) get connected? I'm not quite satisfied with Macbook's built-in keyboard, but use an external keyboard would make me unable to see the words on my screen clearly. Therefore, I think it would be a good idea that turned off the internal keyboard and put the magic keyboard just on top of the useless butterfly keyboard.